# Обособление приложения или тире

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, как оформить это предложение: обособить приложение запятыми с двух сторон или же на месте первого вопроса не ставить никакого знака, а на месте второго — тире, согласно правилу его постановки между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными И.С. в форме Им.п.?

*Выдающийся русский художник (?) Николай Константинович Рерих (?) человек большого таланта, огромной эрудиции, неиссякаемой энергии.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Второй вариант:

*Выдающийся русский художник Николай Константинович Рерих — человек большого таланта, огромной эрудиции, неиссякаемой энергии.*

Основную смысловую нагрузку несёт имя, то, что он *выдающийся русский художник,* просто дополнительное пояснение для тех, кто не знает.